# Edit list of textareras

Tags: php, jquery

Im trying to develop a edit function, where you can edit different of notes by clicking on a simple link "Edit". When u click on this, the note beside the link should tranform from a div, to a editable textarea.

The code:

```
$(".edit").click( function(){
    $('.edit_note').replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<textarea>").text(this.innerHTML);
});

});
```

The problem is that when I click edit on a note, instead of just make that note editable, ALL the notes in the list are editable. How can I make sure of that only the note that I want to edit, is editable?

The notes are looped out from a table in MySQL.

```
foreach($byanat_notering as $key => $value){
    echo "<tr><td width='160' valign='top'><font size='2'>";
    echo substr($value["created"],0,16);
    echo "<br />".$user[$value["users_id"]]["namn"];
    echo "<br/><a href='#' class='edit'>Redigera</a>";
    echo "</td><td width='550' valign='top'><font size='2'>";
    echo "<div class='edit_note'>" . $value["text"] . "</div>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate it out using unique ids, I'm using a variable `$i` for it:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($byanat_notering as $key => $value){
    echo "<tr><td width='160' valign='top'><font size='2'>";
    echo substr($value["created"],0,16);
    echo "<br />".$user[$value["users_id"]]["namn"];
    echo "<br/><a href='#' class='edit' id='edit_". $i ."'>Redigera</a>";
    echo "</td><td width='550' valign='top'><font size='2'>";
    echo "<div class='edit_note' id='edit_note_". $i ."'>" . $value["text"] . "</div>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    $i++;
}
$i = 0;
```

And in JavaScript refer by these unique ids only:

```
$(".edit").click( function(){
    var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').split('_')[1]); //returns the unique integer

    //edit only the div with that integer assigned
    $('#edit_note_'+id).replaceWith(function() {
        return $("<textarea>").text(this.innerHTML);
    });
});
```

I'm using the for loop's index ($i) to match a hrefs against the divs.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. But when I click on my Edit-link, nothhing happens.

Comment: That's strange. Can you copy a few lines of the resultant markup and create a JS Fiddle? I'll work on it.

Comment: Now it works! I wrote var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0] instead of [1] at the end.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What? Even stranger! Because splitting on the underscore should return an array with 2 values: ['edit', 0/1/2...]. So the index must be at the 1st position in the array and not the 0th position. Try thoroughly checking by clicking on all the links.

Comment: I've made some changes in my answer code, check it.

Comment: Hm, it works. But why do you use split? Can u explain? :-)

And another thing, how do I grab the textcontent, the value in the textarea, when it is transformed? .val() don't seem to be the right way to do it?

Comment: Split is akin to explode in php. I associate an index with the link and the same with the div, so that you can identify the div using the link. Also, `val` wont work since the text is actually the content, like a span. So use `text`.

Comment: The text dosen't work.

I've tried like this: $('textarea#edit_note_'+id).text(), but when I alert it, it is declared as undefined.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47169/discussion-between-rutwick-gangurde-and-user500468)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting javascript inside for each loop

```
    <?php
    foreach($byanat_notering as $key => $value){

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".edit-<?php echo $value["users_id"]; ?>").click( function(){
        $('.edit_note-<?php echo $value["users_id"]; ?>').replaceWith(function() {
      return $("<textarea>").text(this.innerHTML);
    });

    });

    </script>

    <?php

        echo "<tr><td width='160' valign='top'><font size='2'>";
        echo substr($value["created"],0,16);
        echo "<br />".$user[$value["users_id"]]["namn"];
        echo "<br/><a href='#' class='edit-".$value["users_id"]."'>Redigera</a>";
        echo "</td><td width='550' valign='top'><font size='2'>";
        echo "<div class='edit_note-".$value["users_id"]."'>" . $value["text"] . "</div>";
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Nope... That isn't needed. Just putting a unique id for the ahref and matching it with the div will do.

Comment: as you wish, i thought it should take unique id with every loop so...but funda is same, what i have used & you are telling........

Comment: Your answer will work too, but it will add additional script tags in the page. So for 1000 values, it will add 1000 script tags! My answer does the same thing, but using his currently implemented code.